# Sorting reputation changes by time should show all reputation changes sorted by time

Tags: feature-request, reputation, profile-page, timestamps

The primary reason to sort reputation changes by time is to understand the chronology of events. But this purpose is largely defeated by the fact that only the last event is shown for every post:

[image: time]

The events are chronologically sorted -- except they are not, because those six upvotes did not all come at 12:38, and other five did not come at 23:17.  The only way to see the full *timeline* of events is to switch to grouping by *posts*, and expand all of them. And then, of course, the timeline is permuted:

[image: post]

It seems the only way to reconstruct the sequence of events of a day is to choose the latter view and re-sort by time in a spreadsheet or something. I think this is suboptimal.

Comment: Here's the bizarrely simple way to view events sorted chronologically: view the page in mobile theme. The only option is what you're asking for. It should absolutely be an option on the full site